# Can I travel in Schengen states until the last day of the validity on my D-visa/residence permit

Tags: schengen, iceland, long-stay-visas, denmark

I am a Chinese citizen working in Denmark. I have a Danish D-visa and temporary Danish residence permit valid until end of October, 2019. I am traveling to Iceland as a tourist in August 2019. I saw that Iceland requires that the validity of qualified visa-exempt passport/ID be at least three months beyond intended stay (https://www.utl.is/index.php/en/who-does-not-need-a-visa).

Does this requirement also apply to my Danish D-Visa/Danish residence permit?

Comment: The requirement does not apply to the visa or residence permit.

Answer (score 2):

The three month requirement applies to all *passports* (except EU/EEA ones), no matter whether they are visa-exempt or not. So the point is not to require in particular that "visa-exemptness" lasts for three months after departure, which I think is the source of your confusion.

The *visa*, if you need one, only needs to be valid on the days you're actually present.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter, Iceland wants you to **be able to leave**. To make sure that you can go home again, they insist that your passport is valid several months beyond your planned date of departure.

Iceland also wants you to have **a valid visa while you stay**. That means when you arrive your visa should be valid to the day you are *planning* to depart, and you should depart before it expires. It might be a good idea to save yourself stress and have a day or two to spare, in case of delays or changes in plans, but that is not required.